# Counter wont increment by decimals

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking the plunge into javascript and have thus far have been relatively successful in what I've been trying to do. Although I realize that most of what I'm doing is probably being done incorrectly, or inefficiently.

For my first "project" I was trying to make a basic game. Click on the pickaxe, and it adds +1 to your total rocks. After you hit 5 rocks you can buy a shovel which will start generating rocks for you at a rate of one per second. I've currently had to set this to 1 per second as nothing under 1 seems to work.

**My code (It's still somewhat messy as I've been tweaking it a lot):**

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mibay/19/edit)**

**HTML:**

```
Total Rocks: <input id="txtNumber" type="text" value="0" onfocus="this.blur()" style=" border:none; text-align:center; background-color:transparent;" />
<br>

<img style="border:0;" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130308043142/minecraftpocketedition/images/6/6d/Pickaxe_1.jpeg" onclick="javascript:add()">
<br>

Rocks per second: <input id="perSec" type="text" value="0" onfocus="this.blur()" style="width:30px; border:none; text-align:center; background-color:transparent;" />
<br>     

Shovel(<input id="shovelCount" type="text" value="0" onfocus="this.blur()" style="width:20px; border:none; text-align:center; background-color:transparent;" />): 5 rocks 

<input id="shovelBuy" type="button" value="Buy" onclick="javascript:shovel()"/>

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var totalRocks = 0;
var rocksPerSec = 0;
    function increment() {
       var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
       var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value, 10) + rocksPerSec;
       txtNumber.value = newNumber;
    }
setInterval(function(){increment();}, 1000);

function add()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value, 10) + 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function shovel()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var value = parseInt(txtNumber.value, 10);
  if(value >= 5){
    var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value, 10) - 5;
    txtNumber.value = newNumber;
    var shovelCount = document.getElementById("shovelCount");
    var newCount = parseInt(shovelCount.value, 10) + 1;
    shovelCount.value = newCount;

    rocksPerSec = rocksPerSec +1;
    return false;
  } 
}
```

**My Question:** Why can't I increment the counter (rockPerSec) by a decimal value?

Comment: You could use parseFloat instead of parseInt everywhere ;)

Comment: I know pretty much nothing. I'm literally piecing together codes and tweaking them until I understand what they do. I shall look that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9vbK6/) fiddle..You basically had to replace `parseInt()` with `parseFloat()` and if you're asking "Why?", the answer is because if you want to increment the numeber of rocks by 0.2 for example, `parseInt(0.2)` is always 0. So you would always add 0.2 to 0 and parse it back to 0..Hope it helps..

```
var totalRocks = 0;
var rocksPerSec = 0;
    function increment() {
       var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
       var newNumber = parseFloat(txtNumber.value, 10) + rocksPerSec;
       txtNumber.value = newNumber;
    }
setInterval(function(){increment();}, 1000);

function add()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseFloat(txtNumber.value, 10) + 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function shovel()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var value = parseFloat(txtNumber.value, 10);
  if(value >= 5){
    var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value, 10) - 5;
    txtNumber.value = newNumber;
    var shovelCount = document.getElementById("shovelCount");
    var newCount = parseFloat(shovelCount.value, 10) + 1;
    shovelCount.value = newCount;

    rocksPerSec = rocksPerSec + 0.2;
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Icepickle mentioned this in the comments and it fixed it. (: But I'll copy my comment I left to him. "What would cause the results I'm seeing here? jsbin.com/mibay/21/edit click 5 times, buy a shovel and watch the counter go up. It's incrementing by 0.01 but eventually shows extra decimal places"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439040/why-does-adding-two-decimals-in-javascript-produce-a-wrong-result#answer-3439125) might help you...

Comment: Hmm that's quite an interesting read. Although, I didn't see much on how  to limit it to two decimal points.

Comment: You could use Math.round(num * 100) / 100

Comment: I actually tried that but it seemed to make no difference. Either that or I was doing it wrong. I know very little about JS at this point. haha

Comment: Nevermind, my bad. I was adding it to the wrong spot, got it! Thanks a lot for your help! :D

Comment: Glad I helped :).. I edited my fiddle form above to [>this<](http://jsfiddle.net/9vbK6/1/) and now it works just like you want if you still need it..

Answer (score 1):

As a help for your first project, i thought i show a suggestion of structuring code

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8CJS/

where you can start the code by using

```
var miner = new Miner();
miner.start();
```

it also allows resetting and stopping (or rather pauze) your current game. Your html code changes when relative properties are changed, and added some functions which i would normally borrow from jquery :)