# What happens if SQL sum() reach type capacity (overflow)?

Tags: sql, integer-overflow

I understand that question is vendor dependent but ask should I worry if aggregate function like `SUM` operate on small type?

For example MariaDB uses 4 bytes for type `INT`. Developers may assume that each transaction have amount no bigger then a few thousands.

But what happen if we try to get income for a whole year for all departments? E.g.:

```
-- CREATE TABLE income (dt DATETIME, department INT, amount INT);
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM income WHERE dt BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

It looks dumb to increasing storage size only to fix overflow issue with aggregate function `SUM`.

What I should worry about? Are there any guarantee or clarification from SQL 92/99/2008 standards?

Are there any special support from JDBC drivers?

Should I rewrite select in form:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(amount AS BIGINT)) FROM income
  WHERE dt BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Yes it is vendor-specific, and casting as bigint will help.  Could you overflow a bigint? theoretically.  So you need to, based on the data you will be storing, could you possibly overflow that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for correction, fixed! If SQL server engine handle overflow what should I do on client side? I should select larger datatype in JDBC/ODBC client code?

Comment: On the client side you have to take that into account, yes.

Comment: BTW: In general, for an income, I would always use `float`. It's the best versatile dataype for all kind of calculations. Also, floating-point operations are very fast, since every CPU has integrated a FPU (floating point unit).

Comment: Is that applicable to SQL **float** type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439040/why-does-adding-two-decimals-in-javascript-produce-a-wrong-result

Comment: @SQLOTL: except that `float` is an *approximate* data type and you can never be sure that you retrieve the same value that you store. It should **never** be used in any financial operatoin. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I know these dicussions over `decimal` vs `float`. I also know the technical and mathematical fundamentals very well. Still, I find that ridiculous. Perhaps for banks, OK. But we have a mass data reporting system and we need **fast** real-time-processing of big sums and various calculations. Therefore I always use `float` which is much faster. Results are rounded at 2 digits. In 25 years, I **never** had a problem. Believe me, I have really experience with big companies.

Answer (score 4):

It's rather easy to test on mysql:

32bit overflow:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select pow(2,31) as x
    union all
    select pow(2,31)
    union all
    select pow(2,31)
) as bignums;
+------------+
| sum(x)     |
+------------+
| 6442450944 | // returned as a "bigint"
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

64bit:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select pow(2,63) as x
    union all
    select pow(2,63)
    union all
    select pow(2,63)
) as bignums;
+-----------------------+
| sum(x)                |
+-----------------------+
| 2.7670116110564327e19 | // returned as float
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Double:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select 1.7e+308 as x
    union all
    select 1.7e+308
    union all
    select 1.7e+308
) as bignums;
+--------+
| sum(x) |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

It's rather easy to test on mysql:

32bit overflow:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select pow(2,31) as x
    union all
    select pow(2,31)
    union all
    select pow(2,31)
) as bignums;
+------------+
| sum(x)     |
+------------+
| 6442450944 | // returned as a "bigint"
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

64bit:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select pow(2,63) as x
    union all
    select pow(2,63)
    union all
    select pow(2,63)
) as bignums;
+-----------------------+
| sum(x)                |
+-----------------------+
| 2.7670116110564327e19 | // returned as float
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Double:

```
mysql> select sum(x) from (
    select 1.7e+308 as x
    union all
    select 1.7e+308
    union all
    select 1.7e+308
) as bignums;
+--------+
| sum(x) |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```

---

comment followup:

```
mysql> describe overflow
    -> ;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| x     | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| y     | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| z     | double     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from overflow;
+------------+---------------------+---------+
| x          | y                   | z       |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2147483647 | 9223372036854775807 | 1.7e308 |
| 2147483647 | 9223372036854775807 | 1.7e308 |
| 2147483647 | 9223372036854775807 | 1.7e308 |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(x), sum(y), sum(z) from overflow;
+------------+----------------------+--------+
| sum(x)     | sum(y)               | sum(z) |
+------------+----------------------+--------+
| 6442450941 | 27670116110564327421 |      0 |
+------------+----------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What data type does `pow(2,31)` return? bigint or int ?

Comment: well, i get the exact same value output if I hardcode 2147483648 instead of pow(...). pow(2,63) does return a float.

Comment: hmm. having trouble saving another edit, but hardcoding the 2^63 value returns 27670116110564327424 , which exceeds a 64bit int's max. very interesting/weird.

Comment: Hm well, but then, `pow(2,31)` does not return a 4-byte `int`, and so the situation is different from what the OP asked. For a correct test, we should setup a test table with dataype `int`, and fill at least two records, such that there will happen an overflow when summing up.

Comment: See last edit above. set up a new table, and basically got the same results. Looks like it just fails "upwards" to a larger capacity type, until it hits a real ceiling and fails as "0".

Comment: Note that Postgres will not silently return zero for the "overflow" example, it will correctly report an error.

Comment: Oracle will actually return "infinity" for the overflow example with the data type `binary_double`.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres handles this without overflow or truncation:

From the manual:

> sum(expression), Return Type: bigint for smallint or int arguments, numeric for bigint arguments, otherwise the same as the argument data type

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

And a quick test proves that:

```
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> create table x (amount int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=>
postgres=> insert into x values (2147483647), (2147483647);
INSERT 0 2
postgres=> select sum(amount)
wbtest-> from x;
    sum
------------
 4294967294
(1 row)

postgres=>
```

---

Interesting enough the SQL standard requires the statement to *fail* in this situation:

> If, during the computation of the result of AF, an intermediate result is not representable in the declared type of the site that contains that intermediate result, then
>   
>   ...
>   Otherwise, an exception condition is raised: data exception — numeric value out of range.

<sup>(AF = aggregate function)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you right, you are asking what happens in case of an overflow.

At least for SQL Server, look up this documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187810%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Here it says what the return type of `sum()` is for specific input types:

```
Expression result               Return type
------------------------------------------------
tinyint                         int
smallint                        int
int                             int
bigint                          bigint
decimal category (p, s)         decimal(38, s)
money and smallmoney category   money
float and real category         float
```

That means, there **can** indeed be an overflow. So I recommend you to use the type `float` or `money` for salaries, instead of the type `int`.

Comment: Thanks, at least some vendors supply info. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sum/ have no any statements (( I reached vote up limit, will do tomorrow.