# Adding 2 numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

While adding 2 numbers I am getting a lengthy decimal part

Pasting the code below.

Number(200.59) + Number(100) = 
300.59000000000003
//Expected result 300.59

Comment: that's how floating points will work , use `toFixed()` method

Comment: and also visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439040/why-does-adding-two-decimals-in-javascript-produce-a-wrong-result), you will find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You could round the number to keep only 2 decimals:

```js
var input = 300.59000000000003
var result = (Math.round(input*100)/100);
alert(result);
```

Comment: Vijay , You are rounding it . But I need to round only if this scenario occurs.