# Rounding a Number variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function sellByte() {
if (player.bytes >= 1) {
    player.bytes = player.bytes - 1;
    player.money = player.money + 0.10;
    document.getElementById("bytes").innerHTML = "Bytes: " + player.bytes;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "$" + player.money;
   }
}
```

And whenever I sell a Byte my money value ends up looking like $10.00000003 or something along those lines, how would I go about rounding the money value UP every time this function is run?

Comment: parseFloat and toFixed are your best friends

Comment: Do you want to *fix* the rounding errors you get from floating point math, or do you just want to *display* them as rounded numbers?

Comment: But actually your question already has answers here at stackoverflow and you should have tied to find them

Comment: you can refer to this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439040/why-does-adding-two-decimals-in-javascript-produce-a-wrong-result

Comment: There are [*many, many duplicates*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+rounding).

Comment: There is also this answer for [*Round to at most 2 decimal places*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript/12830454#12830454).

Answer (score 1):

Working with float numbers in JS is very [tricky](http://modernweb.com/2014/02/17/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-points/).  My suggestion is to operate only with smaller units (cents instead of dollars) and then you will only deal with integers and will not have similar issues.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Math.round(player.money* 100) / 100` for 2 decimal rounding.

Comment: Why -1? Now somebody added duplicate of similar answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use any of the following code

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

using fixed Method

```
var numb = 123.23454;
```

numb = numb.toFixed(2);

or you can refer following link for more help

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round