# Subtracting Truncated Numbers: Result isn't truncated?

Tags: python, truncated

I'm trying to create a function that will divide a number into categories based on a specified percent (okay, a budget.)

I've taken the divided floats, grabbed a test truncate function off the web, and truncated everything after the hundredth place. This is to prevent the sum of all the categories being greater than the initial amount. Then I subtract the total sum of the categories from the initial amount to get a "remainder," which in my example should be 0.03, or 3 cents.

```
def budget_calc(amount):

    budget = {"t":0.10,
            "c":0.50,
            "s":0.20,
            "e":0.05,
            "c/m":0.05,
            "tr":0.05,
            "o":0.03,
            "g/d":0.02}

    def truncate(x, d):

        return int(x*(10.0**d))/(10.0**d)


    def multp(key):

        cate = truncate(amount * budget.get(key), 2)

        return cate


    new_amounts = {'t': multp('t'),
              'c': multp('c'),
              's': multp('s'),
              'e': multp('e'),
              'c/m': multp('c/m'),
              'tr': multp('tr'),
              'o': multp('o'),
              'g/d': multp('g/d')}

    remainder = amount - sum(new_amounts.values())
    new_amounts.update(remainder = remainder)

    return new_amounts
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
budget_calc(148.72)

     {'t': 14.87,
     'c': 74.36,
     's': 29.74,
     'e': 7.43,
     'c/m': 7.43,
     'tr': 7.43,
     'o': 4.46,
     'g/d': 2.97,
     'remainder': 0.029999999999972715} #<-- this number should only contain two decimal points
```

So somewhere along the line the "truncate" function is only displaying the truncated number, not actually getting rid of the excess digits? The math in there is wrong as well, 148.72 - the sum of all the truncated numbers (148.69) should be 0.03. That's what it seems like, an additional diagnosis would be great.

Comment: You may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken to get a basic understanding of (binary) floating-point arithmetics. You could use the `decimal` package to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You never applied `truncate` to the `remainder` calculation, you just summed the truncated numbers and subtracted them. Every addition in the `sum` includes a possibility of a small precision issue, and the subtraction introduces another, and truncating the results will cause serious problems (because an error that reduces the value even a little will cause a huge error when you truncate). If you want to round it consistently, you have to round it every time. I'd also recommend using `math.fsum` to reduce the error on your summation:

```
>>> d = {'t': 14.87,
         'c': 74.36,
         's': 29.74,
         'e': 7.43,
         'c/m': 7.43,
         'tr': 7.43,
         'o': 4.46,
         'g/d': 2.97}
>>> import math
>>> sum(d.values())        # Loses precision
148.69000000000003
>>> math.fsum(d.values())  # More accurate!
148.69
>>> 148.72 - sum(d.values())  # Already lost precision, so result wrong
0.029999999999972715
>>> 148.72 - math.fsum(d.values())  # Sadly, even with accurate fsum, final subtraction is "wrong"
0.030000000000001137
>>> round(148.72 - math.fsum(d.values()), 2)  # But we can always round it off
0.03
```

All that said, trying to do this with `float`s is inherently error-prone; `float` precision is expressed in binary, and you want decimal precision. If you need decimal precision, I'd strongly recommend you use [the `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) which has a million knobs for making it behave *exactly* the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to imprecision in float calculations, just like

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

in javascript.

You can find more information about that here [Why does adding two decimals in Javascript produce a wrong result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439040/why-does-adding-two-decimals-in-javascript-produce-a-wrong-result)

A solution would be to round instead of truncating, and also round your reminder.